# "cannot be resolved to a type" error after adding depenency in aem project

Tags: maven, dependency-injection, aem

I've added Jsoup dependency in my AEM project. After that I receive error "com.project.core.models.MySlingModel cannot be resolved to a type" when I use Jsoup in my OSGI service class injected in MySlingModel.

Comment: This error comes, if either you bundle couldn't be started (check under /system/console/bundles), or if a required dependency couldn't be injected (then make it @Optional). I think, it is the first one.

Comment: You're right, my bundle is "installed", but I cannot understand why. I checked this site and google and didn't found the solution that could fix my issue. 
I got this in my bundle:
`org.jsoup,version=[1.14,2) -- Cannot be resolved`
`org.jsoup.nodes,version=[1.14,2) -- Cannot be resolved`

Comment: Then you haven't embedded jsoup in your bundle. You just added the dependency, which cannot be resolved by the OSGi container now. How to embed a JAR into a bundle is pretty advanced maven and OSGi stuff. Unfortunately, we cannot help you from here. It heavily depends on your current maven-build, and which plugins you are using. Please try to get help from someone, to extend your pom.xml's.

Comment: With help, I mean some expert on-site. Even someone with experience about your current Maven-setup will probably need 30-60 minutes to get this done, have it tested, etc.

Comment: I just looked it up. It seems, that jsoup is already packaged as an OSGi bundle. so you can just put it into an install folder e.g. /apps/myproject/install . You could embed it into an package.
Look here for an example: https://github.com/alberndt/aem-app-integration/blob/a6f904b75042a81e7b96cc03ed33892441b3e7a7/server/aem/package/pom.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 6 [dependency scopes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) in maven. Usually all maven dependencies in AEM are included with a `<scope>provided</scope>`. This means the dependent jar version is already present inside the felix container. For example when you add

```
           <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.21</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
```

when maven builds the jar, it will not embed these dependencies. But during runtime it ll expect this version will be present in the JDK or felix container. Fortunately felix also PROVIDES the same version jar and code works.

Incase of jsoup, this is NOT available in the felix. Thats means you have to force push the jar from outside into the felix container. There are 2 ways to do this, package the jar into its bundle and push into felix. But better approach is to [include](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html#includeArtifactIds) the dependency so that along with core.jar, the jsoup.jar will also be pushed into felix container each time during deployment.

Steps to do this:

1. From the parent pom.xml, add the dependency. This will add jsoup with compile scope

```
           <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
                <version>1.12.1</version>
            </dependency>
```

2. Inside the core pom.xml, under maven-dependency-plugin, add another execution step as shown. This will copy the jar into felix

```
               <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependency</id>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                      <includeArtifactIds>jsoup</includeArtifactIds>
                    </configuration>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
```

3. Next we have to bind the right version. Under bnd-maven-plugin add another execution step like this

```
<executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>bnd-process</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>bnd-process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <bnd><![CDATA[
Import-Package: org.jsoup.*;version=1.12.1,!sun.misc.*;resolution:=optional,*
-exportcontents: ${packages;VERSIONED},org.jsoup.*;version=1.12.1
Include-Resource: target/dependency/jsoup-1.12.1.jar
Bundle-ClassPath: ., jsoup-1.12.1.jar
Sling-Model-Packages: com.myproject.core.models
-snapshot: ${tstamp;yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS}
Bundle-DocURL:
-plugin org.apache.sling.caconfig.bndplugin.ConfigurationClassScannerPlugin
                                 ]]></bnd>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
```

4. Finally add the jsoup dependency to core pom.xml like this

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Make sure not to leave any syntax error in pom.xml else build will fail.